# React demorando ao abrir dependencias gráficas

Tags: react, react-native

Após executar os comandos:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native start
```

no cmd, não consigo executar a parte grafica do Reactuy-Android
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tem o Android instalado
Como consigo corrigir isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parece que não tens o `yarn` instalado. O `yarn` é uma alternativa ao `npm`, ou seja um motor para ir buscar componentes que estejam na npm.

Tens de instalar globalmente:

```
npm install -g yarn
```

Comment: Fiz a instalação..porém continua demorando abrir a interface gráfica do android..O que devo fazer agora ??

Comment: @alexjosesilva o erro é o mesmo ou agora é um novo?

Comment: O erro é o mesmo

Comment: O erro é mesmo não mudou nada!

Comment: Encontrrei o erro JDK diferente do jre

Comment: @alexjosesilva bom dia, foi hora de dormir aqui na Europa :) Se o erro era outro dá uma resposta explicar e marca como aceite!

Answer (score 1):

Como a resposta do Sergio disse, se apareceu erro do yarn, então tem que ter certeza de que o mesmo fora instalado.

E o que é "Reacty"??

Como você instalou o React Native? Usando o **npm**? Se você seguir o [guia oficial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html), então basta usar:

```
react-native init AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```

Ou você pode rodar o aplicativo diretamente do Android Studio (recomendo).